# making a native app that is based on a website

Tags: ios, native

I am looking for some resources (blog posts, tutorials, etc) on creating a native iOS app from a pre-existing website.  It seems that the easiest way to do it would be to use a `UIWebView` and just load the website there, but I am interested in making native app.

Unfortunately, all Google searches I have tried just turn up results for web apps :(

(sorry if this question is vague)

Comment: This is not a good question for this site, which focuses on specific, discrete programming questions.

Comment: Sorry.  I thought about asking it on UX, but didn't think it would fit there either.  Where would you recommend for next time ?

Comment: I don't think you've posed a question that really has an answer.  I suggest digging into the specifics.  What are the issues keeping you from building a native app, and how does the fact that it's intended as a website replacement/substitute make it different from any other app?

Comment: Use uiwebview or write your own browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would write a webservice that provides the information to display. The website and the app would then send the appropriate requests and display the received data. Both can implement their own drawing/display code. This also enables to add maybe an Android or Windows Phone app later on without having to manage a seperate set of data for each application.

If you want to use the data existing on the website I think `UIWebView` is your only option (unless you want to write your own browser).

Comment: this is what I wanted to know, thanks

Answer (score 2):

What my TidBITS News app does, to show users what's going on at the tidbits.com Web site, is to use RSS. The stuff that appears at the Web site is also pushed out on an RSS feed. The app consults that feed. Now it has the data, so it can express that same information in a native app. It does use a UIWebView, but that's to display some of the RSS data (which is HTML to begin with), not to view the Web site itself.

Comment: I will check your app out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hey u can use the web view, add the requried framework, then look up for parser.

And yea one more thing
JSON Parsing will help u with this ....

its all about UIWebView Connected with XML with JSON Parsing.